# Pi 3 Boot with UART console

Tags: raspbian, uart, pi-3

I use Raspberry Pi 3 with image "RASPBIAN JESSIE" which is 2016-02-26 build. I plug in micro-usb to power on. Then I use USB to TTL adapter to try to login. I've set baud rate 115200, and connect GND, Pi's TXD0 to TTL's RX, Pi's RXD0 to TTL's TX. But I only saw mojibake. I've tried other usual baud rate and comes same results. I also try use this image on Pi 2, and it behaves normally.
Does anyone knows how to login with uart on Pi 3?

Answer (score 3):

I found answer here:
https://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/12311

Briefly it's due to Pi 3 default enable bluetooth which supplants uart on GPIO 14/15. So we need to disable bluetooth.

Comment: I can confirm this is still the case on the March 15 (2016) release of Raspbian Jessie and Jessie Lite. Great Answer.