# Getting garbage characters on RPi3 UART console, logs on HDMI are perfect

Tags: pi-3, uart

I have searched a lot on internet and tried all suggested solutions like criss-cross connection, checking loose connections, changing baud_rates and using GND connection for UART, but nothing seems to work so far. Moreover most of the previous solution seekers were using Raspbian, whereas I am not. Hence, putting this question to get scenario specific solutions. I do not have resources to do any HW debugging, but assuming my RPi3 is not faulty.

This is first time I am using RPi3 (after years on beaglebone), so please do not assume anything.

I was trying to boot U-boot on RPi3.

I created a FAT partition on SD card and copied all the .dat, .elf and bootcode.bin files in the /boot folder on SD card. These firmware files were copied from the official [Raspberry pi firmware Github repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware).

I compiled U-boot and copied u-boot.bin file on the SDCard. I have created the following `config.txt` file on SD card to pick uboot binary by the firmware :

```
enable_uart=1
arm_control=0x200
kernel=u-boot.bin
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
```

U-boot logs are coming fine on HDMI , but I get garbage characters on Minicom (set at 115200, 8N1).

I am using the [FTDI 232R-3V3 cable](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232R_CABLES.pdf) and have connected the RX, TX and GND on pins 6, 8 and 10 (criss-cross connection). HDMI port is also connected.

What could be the reason for this? I read [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45007/garbage-on-raspberry-pi-console) that BT operation could interfere, but I am not sure if that is applicable to me since I am not using Raspbian and only loading U-boot. If this is the case, how can I fix it? What other things I can try apart from mentioned at the top?

**EDIT**

This is how the garbage characters look like. So when i type, some random character k pops up, when type x, ` may come up. Otherwise output remains blank: 
[image]

Comment: You have said lots about what you aren't doing but not provided any concrete data.

Comment: *criss-cross connection* - so,  TX to RX and RX to TX? ... that's a correct and only valid connection, not "criss cross", because transmit should connect to receive, not transmit,

Comment: *I read here that BT operation could interfere* - so, did you try the solutions?

Comment: Perhaps you can try init uart clk and uart bd in your config.txt: (1) init_uart_baud initial UART baud rate. Default 115200,
(2) init_uart_clock initial UART clock. Default 3000000 (3MHz),
(3) eLinux RPiconfig: https://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Boot.

Comment: What baudrate did you set in software? There's no point in changing baud rates if you know the correct one. Also, what does "using GND connection for UART" mean? UART has 3 pins (TX RX GND) and it won't work unless you correctly connect all three.

Comment: Those  garbage characters, what do they look like ? Notwithstanding the possible issue with Bluetooth, can you try with something else than `minicom` eg `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`. I would also try different UART cables if possible.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev : I used the default one first which is 115200. Then I put other ones like 2400, 4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, 38400, 57600 in config.txt and minicom , but same behaviour. I connected TX of pi to RX of serial and vice-versa and GND of both pi and cable.

Comment: @Anonymous : I tried screen as well but did not work

Comment: @Anonymous : I had one more exact same cable which I use on MinnowBoard Max, but still the same garbage on the screen. I can guarantee that at least this second cable is not faulty as it works with my minnow.

Comment: Looks like I have narrowed down the cause. I installed raspbian and on the same setup (no different cable, no wiring change, no baud rate change - 115200 on minicom) I am able to get the serial console perfectly. This means either the firmware that I am using or the u-boot I am using are faulty. Can someone please point me to a working combination of firmware files+u-boot repo.

Comment: I pulled the .dat, .elf and bootcode.bin files from /boot/ folder of Raspbian OS and kept the same u-boot.bin and config.txt files. It worked !!!! This means only the firmware files are perhaps (or the combination) not correct. Can someone please take a look on the repo in the question and point me why those FW files are not working.