# Blank terminal in Pi0 UART connection

Tags: gpio, serial, pi-zero, uart

Following this tutorial exactly: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview

i.e.:

- Drivers are installed
- UART line is added and enabled

I get a blank screen when trying to access the serial terminal using MacOS and Linux. I can boot the Pi0 and see that everything is working when hooking it up to a display.

Using CoolTerm, the application just freezes up.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: If you followed the tutorial exactly it either works, the tutorial is wrong, or you **didn't follow exactly** - unless you tell us what **YOU** did no one can help.

Comment: I DID exactly what the tutorial asked. The other possibility is there there is/are assumption(s) not stated in the tutorial or anywhere else as far as I can tell. For instance, maybe the tutorial only works for certain versions of Raspbian (or default configuration has certain parameters disabled somewhere), maybe I’ve run into a bug, etc...

Comment: My question stemmed from here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82911/cant-login-to-pi0-console-from-pi3-b-via-uart-serial-usb-tty-adapter

Comment: But since that ^ seemed like a dead end, I wanted to make the question more general and elaborate that it doesn’t seem to matter what the host (USB-end) is, I get the same result. Also I can see Raspbian boot now that I have a miniHDMI to HMDI adapter

Comment: Did you try connecting your rx and tx lines and typing in your keyboard? That will make sure the cable works. Also check the baud rate, make sure you specify the baud rate in the coolterm settings. The guide you linked says 115200

Comment: So I did that and then in minicom I enabled local echo but I don’t get anything back, however, connecting the lines and running linux-serial-test (a repo on github) I get more or less the same amount of data transmitted and received. So I’m inclined to say that it is not the adapter though I just purchased a CP2102 to try out. I believe I am currently using PL2303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Pi Zero (not the Pi Zero Wireless), your UART should be acessible as `/dev/ttyAMA0` or `/dev/serial0`. You should check whether the UART hardware is working and whether a login process is initiated on it.

To check the hardware:

- *Disable* the Linux UART console using `raspi-config` or by editing the config files manually
- Reboot
- Short TX and RX pins with a wire
- Run a terminal on your RPi with that UART, e.g. `minicom -D /dev/serial0` or `screen /dev/serial0`
- Type something: you should see whatever you type due to RX/TX loopback

To see the login process:

- Enable the Linux UART console using `raspi-config` or by editing the config files manually
- Reboot
- Try runin a terminal on your RPi with that UART, you should see a "Device busy" error.
- Run `ps -t /dev/serial0 /dev/ttyAMA0` on your RPi as root. You should see a process attached to one of these devices.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - its been a nightmare to get my Pi0 connected to the internet to install `screen`. While console is disabled I just get a blinking cursor with nothing echoed to screen. Any ideas?

Comment: @SterlingButters Assuming you're trying to check the hardware with a loopback wire, that would mean you either use wrong pins or your pins are damaged. It's practically impossible to configure a UART wrong in loopback configuration.

Comment: Hmmm I did solder the GPIO header myself but I figured since I was getting power to the RPi0 everything else would be fine. It doesn’t matter what direction the header is installed right?

Comment: When I said about damaged pins, I didn't mean mechanical damage but rather electrical. Though it wouldn't hurt to check the soldering if you have any doubts. Of course, pin header can face either direction.

Comment: So using a different Pi0 I am able to get input echoed when "checking hardware" on `/dev/serial0`. However while "initiating login process" (if the RX & TX short is still in place) I get a hung boot sequence between a flashing gray screen with an ellipsis in the middle (all of which doesn't look very good). If I remove the short during boot and then reconnect afterward, I get `cannot exec 'serial0': No such file directory` - any ideas?

Comment: ok it looks like the boot sequence is advancing some - tho it takes much longer with the short - will post if completes

Comment: Ok it looks like the hang is now at `((1 of 2) A start job is running for LSB: Prepare con...53s / no limit` - is this the same as `Device busy`?

Comment: OMG FINALLY IT WORKS!!! I can see the login shell on my mac. I guess there is something wrong electrically with the GPIO header connection on the other RPi0. Thank you so much for your help!!!